# How to re-set up Schedule Refresh in Power BI with SA Account?

Tags: powerbi, gateway, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have certain reports that auto refresh at some specific time. I have used my corporate ID and using that ID, I have install Power BI Gateway for refreshing on-premise data. I have then configured my reports using the gateway that I have installed on my Windows Server.

Now, we have setup a new SA account that has its own Corporate email address, power BI pro license and its own username/password. Now I want my reports to use the SA account for setting up Gateway as well as reports will be refreshed using SA Accounts' Gateway setting.

What changes I need to make? The server where both the gateways are installed is a common single server.

**Steps that I have taken so far**:

1. Sign in with SA Acccount in the Gateway installer
2. Enter recovery key in the Gateway installer
3. Gateway is installed succesfully using SA's account corporate email ID and password

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refresh can be configured via API, using the

`POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/refreshes`

REST call.

See this for more info:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/